# Why is there no need to mark the move constructor of a type with a deleted copy constructor as deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

Consider `std::mutex`. I understand why `std::mutex` should not be movable. But its copy constructor is clearly marked as deleted, but I have not seen such a declaration for its move constructor. So why does cppreference say `std::mutex` is not movable?

As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), there are many preconditions that are not fulfilled that prevent the implicit move constructor. But I could not find the reason for this question. I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

**I really don't think this one(en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex) is the user-defined destructor for `std::mutex`.**

Comment: "there are many preconditions that are not fulfilled that prevent the implicit move constructor." - You have not looked closely enough. `mutex` has a user-defined destructor.

Comment: @SebastianRedl &TonyTannous But there is no non-default destructor for std::mutex. Could you give me some hint? **Do you mean this one(en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex) is the user-defined destructor? I am shocked.**

Comment: The answer is it's implementation dependent. Not all implementations provide a trivial destructor for mutex.

Comment: You are still trying to do what you should not. A mutex is NOT a C++ object. It's a kernel  object wrapped in a C++ class. Please conform to the appropriate restrictions.

Comment: @michael chourdakis from his point of view cppref shows nothing other than a default destructor so he is confused to why move is not marked deleted.

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes, that is the key point.

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons why the implicit move constructor is not generated by the compiler:

- `std::mutex` might have a user-defined destructor. On some platforms, mutex objects allocate memory, so the destructor has to clean that up, for example by calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()`.
- The copy constructor is explicitly deleted, which counts as being "user-declared".

So why is the standard written in such a way that the above cases prevent the generation of an implicit move constructor? First think of a class where you don't have any constructor/destructor/copy/move operator defined. Then the whole class just behaves as a collection of member variables. The logical thing to do when constructing/destructing/copying/moving such a collection is just to apply the operation on each item individually. However, as soon as you user-define on of those operations, you are adding new semantics to your class, and basically it is no longer just a collection of member variables. The compiler isn't smart enough from looking at the operations you user-defined how to implicit create all the other operations, so the safe thing to do is to not implicit create them.

Comment: I am very grateful for your generous help. I don't mean to doubt what you say. I just want to dig deep and confirm. Quote from your answer[emphasis mine]: The copy assignment operator is explicitly deleted, which **counts as being "user defined".**  I just heard such a saying: "I think deleted counts as it exists and participates in overload resolution but it cannot be called". So while it is deleted it still exists and can be chosen which then makes the program ill-formed." **Is there any material I can refer to? I mean whether it's declared in the C++ Standard or not.**

Comment: @John: "*So while it is deleted it still exists and can be chosen which then makes the program ill-formed.*" What does that have to do with whether a move constructor is implicitly defined or not? The rule is that if you have a user-defined copy constructor, you don't get an implicit move constructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas But the question is whether there is a user-defined copy constructor for `std::mutex`. You see it is marked as deleted. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: @John: "*But the question is whether there is a user-defined copy constructor for std::mutex.*" No, it's not. The question is why having an explicitly deleted copy constructor means that you have an implicitly deleted move constructor. That's what you asked. And it's not "user-**defined**"; it's "user-**declared**"; it's right there in your own link.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry. I am not a native speaker. :(.  Thank you for your patience and help. Could you please tell me why having an explicitly deleted copy constructor means that there is an implicitly deleted move constructor? I have thought about it for a long time.

Comment: @NicolBolas  I don't mean to doubt what you say. I believe you are right. I just want to dig deep and confirm whether I could use this rule in the future. Quote from your answer[emphasis mine]: The copy assignment operator is explicitly deleted, **which counts as being "user defined".** Is there any material I can refer to? **I mean whether it's declared in the C++ Standard or not.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215950/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-john).